# Android Product Flavors Release Build NoClassFound

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-build-type, android-build-flavors

I have created application with 37 product flavors all with two build types debug and release.I ran into a problem when i generated signed APK for a single flavor app crashes giving the following error.

```
ComponentInfo{flavorApplicationId/com.companyname.app.SplashScreen}:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.app.SplashScreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.appname-1/base.apk"]
```

Note that when i am working on debug flavor their is no crash like this and app runs perfectly fine. I have a main package that is needed to be shared by all of the flavors.

In app level build.gradle file i am defining source sets for each flavor like this

```
 sourceSets {
    CashbackKorting.java.srcDir = ['src/main/java']
    CashbackKorting.res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/flavorName/res', 'src/main/res_nl']
    }
```

Please help me out why is that ClassNotFoundException on only release build for activities but not in debug build type and suggest a solution. Thanks

Comment: Is your proguard turned on? Try turning it off and see it if works, if it does then you need to write some proguard rules for it